# Upper estimate for matrix series

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider the vector
$$x_k=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k(I-A)^i A w_{k-i}$$
where symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $0\preceq A\preceq I$ (in positive-definiteness sense, that is $0\le\lambda(A)\le1$) and arbitrary vectors $w_k\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\|w_k\|\le1$.

The goal is to obtain an upper bound for $$\|x_k\| \quad\text{when}\quad k\to\infty$$

All norms are Euclidean.

The estimate should not include matrix $A$ itself, because we know only its 'bounds'.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by $0\leq A\leq I$? Do you mean $0 \leq A_{i,j} \leq I_{i,j}$ when you say $0\leq A\leq I$? So $A$ is diagonal? Or $||A|| \leq ||I|| = 1$ in terms of the matrix norm?

Comment: Also, is it $(\sum_k(I-A)^k)Aw_k$ or $\sum_k((I-A)^kAw_k)$, i.e. is it a sum of operators or of vectors?

Comment: One easy estimate is $\|A\|/(1-\|I-A\|)$ if $\|I-A\|<1$.